# JQuery function is not calling when JQuery Ajax method succeed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am doing a small application in asp.net using JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var imgPoll = new Image();
        imgPoll.src = 'images/red-bar.png';
        if ($("#divVoted").length > 0) //Already voted
        {
            animateResults();
        }
        else {
            $("#rdoPoll0").attr("checked", "checked"); //default select the first Choice

            $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
                $("#divPoll").css("cursor", "wait"); //show wait cursor inside Poll div while processing
                $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "true") //disable the Vote button while processing
                var pID = $("input[id$=hidPollID]").val(); //get Poll ID
                var cID = $("input[name='rdoPoll']:checked").val(); //get the checked Choice
                var data = "{'pID':'" + pID + "', 'cID':'" + cID + "'}"; //create the JSON data to send to server
                jQuery.ajax(
            {

                type: 'POST',

                data: data,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'Poll_CS.aspx/UpdatePollCount',
                success: function(msg)  //show the result
                {
                    //alert("valid");
                    $("#divPoll").css("cursor", "default"); //remove the wait cursor
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "false") //enable the Vote button
                    $("div[id$=divAnswers]").fadeOut("fast").html(msg.d).fadeIn("fast",               function() { animateResults(); });
                }
            });
            });
        }
        function animateResults() {

            $("div[id$=divAnswers] img").each(function() {
                var percentage = $(this).attr("val");
                $(this).css({ width: "0%" }).animate({ width: percentage }, 'slow');
            });
        }
    });
```

After Success of Jquery.ajax method `animateResults()` function is not calling. 
While in local server it is working good whereas in host server it is not working.

Please give suggestion to solve this problem

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: Would you work on your code formatting so we can read it, please?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I doubt we'd be able to help if the same code works on one machine but not the other; looking at the difference between those two machines is more relative than the same piece of code.

Comment: compare the javascript files on both the servers, if you might have forgot to deploy the latest file or so, otherthan that there shouldn't be any reason why it works one machine and not on other.

Comment: what is the "val" attribute of an img? shouldn't it be "width" instead?

Comment: Did you open your firebug console and checked what was returned?

Answer (score 0):

Define your function outside jQuery `.ready()`. Not sure why but that could cause your problem

Comment: it is not recomended to place any jquery code outside jquery.read()